Start counting from 1 and go up to 9 | 7-segment Display
so I have this circuit in Falstad that counts up to 9 (from 0 to 9) but I need to it to count from 1 to 9. In falstad I am using a counter, 7 segment decoder and a 7 segment display. Any thoughts on how to edit the circuit to do what I need
Circuit: on Falstad


Take a screenshot of your circuit instead of asking people to click on a link that could go anywhere. Use a counter with a jam input or if this is a school assignment where you have to use the parts given, show us what approaches you have tried already.

You might look into *parallel-load" 4-bit counter as one approach to solve your problem.

honest answer on "how to edit the circuit": replace all elements but the 7-segment display with a cheap microcontroller? That's how someone from the last ~30 years would build this. In any case, you're also missing series resistors for the LEDs.

Albii, If this a problem related to schoolwork, what are the skills that you are expected to apply and how is it supposed to be performed? (What are you studying at this time? Does it only need to "run" on Falstad?) Otherwise, do you plan on building something with physical parts? Or just on a simulator?

@periblepsis Yes this is a problem related to schoolwork, and itis s needed to showcase the skills earned in Digital Logic subject. It is not necessary to run it on Falstad, I just got accustomed to it. This is just part of that digital clock that I asked in a previous question which you responded also ( and I thank you for that ) but unfortunately  it got closed : ( .

Thank you for your answer @glen_geek

@vir Sorry about that link thing you're right. It is just a school assignment nothing more we don't even have physical parts to build it and we use simulators. Anyways thank you for your time and response

@MarcusMüller thank you for your response!

@Albii Ah. There is a general process for creating a machine that progresses through a finite set of states. Useful both here and for your closed question there. It's straight forward. Probably what you may have been expected to master? (That process is, in fact, why I listed three different ways to solve the same question you had there. Same process, different choices.)

@periblepsis yes probably. I will give you an update about the digital clock if you are interested. I got it to work and count the hours up to 23 and now I am doing days, months and years. I know this digital clock has been done form others before and I myself started from one youtube video I saw (That's the reason I use falstad because I got use to it while watching the video). But I am continuing it on my own logic and trying to understand it, maybe I am not doing a good work and not using a correct approach and that's the reason maybe that my questions might sound stupid.

@Albii The process is shown here, for example. Just start out with a list of states you want, in the order you want them, with all the remaining possible states at the bottom. List out the "next state" that you want for each of the states you want. The next state for the remaining ones is just "don't care" because you will never get one of those so it doesn't matter. Then you develop the k-maps and simplify. (Or use a software tool.) From there it's just adding the logic. You do have to select a FF type. JK is most flexible.

@Albii You may need to adjust your thinking if the starting state is not 0 and if the FF type you select powers up as 0. In this case, you take the $\overline{Q}$ output of the FFs where a 1 is wanted at power-up. This messes with your table. But it works. Or, as you heard here, use a parallel load method. Or use FFs with an asynchronous set/reset that is signaled during power-up.

Use a counter that supports preload, and preload with 1
Falstad

Thanks mate, did the work

A quick and dirty way: use a count from 0 to 8, then insert an incrementer (4-bit adder) to make 1 to 9.

Thank you for your answer!
